# Can the selling price be treated as a random variable?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I have some data from my company that I have been looking at. I have been comparing deals that we have "lost" to deals that we have "won". I have been comparing the product averages and standard deviations, and have found that the average and standard deviation (for some industries) are lower for the "lost" deals.

We sell each product at set prices, but products can have special discounts when requested which causes "random prices." Some products will be sold higher or lower depending on the customer. When I look at the data, the prices are slightly negatively skewed but seem to be normally distributed.

Does this mean that I can treat the price as random and apply the central limit theorem? Also, I will be suggesting more aggressive lower pricing if I can treat the range as normally distributed. Is this logical?

Comment: "*the prices are slightly negatively skewed but seem to be normally distributed*" -- those two statements appear to be contradictory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prices cannot be normally distributed, since they are non-negative. But you write that *actual* prices fluctuate below or above the preset prices.

Denote $p_s$ the preset price and $u$ the special discount or increase above the pre-set price. Then, realized price is

$$p=p_s+u \Rightarrow u=p-p_s$$

Now $u$ is distributed around zero, but not necessarily symmetrically. There is no reason to ignore any skewness present in the data. Go for the [Skew-normal Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution), which has been conceived exactly for modelling skewness.